# Java regex don't count all matches in a given file

Tags: java, regex, matching

As the title says, I have written a java code to count all the matches in a given file using regular expressions, when I run the code, the out is different from the matches in the file. It works perfectly if I separated each string in a new line. Here's my code:

This is the method that should count:

```
private static int countOccurrences(String path, String regex) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher;
    int count = 0;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            if (matcher.find())
                count++;
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return count;
}
```

Here's the code using that method:

```
String regex = "(00966|\\+966)\\d{9}";
int countNumbers = countOccurrences(fileContainsNumbers, regex);
```

Here's the file I read from:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy +966111111111 text of the printing and
>   typesetting industry.+966222222222 Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
>   standard dummy text ever +966333333333 since the 1500s, when an
>   unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled +966444444444
>   +96645789541063 it to make a type specimen book. +966569874514 It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
>   typesetting, remaining +966569874514 essentially unchanged. It was
>   popularised +966569874514 in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
>   sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
>   publishing software like Aldus PageMaker +966555555555 including
>   versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the [find()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) method in the wrong way. Instead of

```
if (matcher.find())
  count++;
```

you should do

```
while (matcher.find())
  count++;
```

You see, you can have *multiple* matches per line. So that method can return true several times for any line that contains those *multiple* matches. But you stop counting after the first true!

In other words: if you want to count all matches on each line, then don't stop counting after the first match on a line!

Comment: Oh I see, thats why it stops counting at first match per line. but will this code loop through the entire file? or  I have to use another loop inside the file's loop?

Comment: Why don't you just try it? I think it should work. You see - you are already looping all the lines in that file. And then you should be looping the matcher in order to count the matches PER line. Replacing IF with WHILE as suggested already ADDs that inner loop that you need!

Comment: It worked perfectly, Thank you very much.. I'll try to find a better way to use "one loop" instead of "nested loops" if possible.

Marked it as an answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept. Final word though: dont put too much energy into that. There is not much point in avoiding that inner loop. You see, in essence, you want to have *multiple* matches per line. *multiple* says **plural**, and **plural** says: looping!

Comment: "in essence, you want to have multiple matches per line. multiple says plural, and plural says: looping!"

Good way of thinking it through!